# Creating an independant jar file with Ant

Tags: java, ant, jar

A basic Java, which displays a GUI window with an image(picture.jpg) and a text label read from app.properties), also uses the log4j library.
It has the following structure(the build and dist directories are added by ant 'build' and 'dist' targets): 
[image: Directory Structure]

[The entire app as an Eclipse project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpsed3xvqsys0ee/DemoApp.zip)

**Basic functionality:**
The 'build' target compiles all source files to the 'build' directory and copies other resources needed for running the app to the 'build' directory. This can be then run with the 'run' target.
The 'dist' target just zips the entire 'build' directory into a jar file and places it to the 'dist' folder.

**The problem**
I want the jar to be completely independant. Currently it runs using the 'runjar' target and also when just clicking on the jar.
However, if I move the jar file elsewhere, it will not start, so it is still dependant on files outside the jar, although the jar contains all the files necessary.
This can also be seen from the jar's **MANIFEST.MF** file.

```
Main-Class: com.my.demo.app.Main
Class-Path: ../build/classes/ ../build/img/ ../build/conf/ ../build/ .
 ./build/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

Also if I'm doing something else wrong, any other feedback is welcome.

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." name="DemoApp" default="build">
    <property file="app.properties"/>

    <path id="compile.classpath" description="Classpath for compiling classes to 'build' dir">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="run.classpath" description="Classpath for running compiled app in 'build' dir">
        <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}"/>
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}/img"/>
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}/conf"/>
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
        <fileset dir="${build.dir}/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean" description="Remove files generated by 'build' and 'dist'">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="Compiles the source files">
        <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
        <javac
            srcdir="${src.dir}"
            destdir="${build.classes.dir}"
            debug="true"
            debuglevel="lines,vars,source"
            encoding="utf-8"
            compiler="modern"
            target="1.7"
            source="1.7"
            includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="compile" description="Builds project">
        <!--Copy app.properties to build/app.properties-->
        <copy todir="${build.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*.properties"/>
        </copy>

        <!--Copy picture.jpg to build/img/picture.jpg-->
        <copy todir="${build.dir}/img">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/etc/img"/>         
        </copy>

        <!--Copy jars in lib to build/lib-->
        <copy todir="${build.dir}/lib">
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        </copy>

        <!--copy log4j.xml to build/conf/log4j.xml -->
        <copy todir="${build.dir}/conf">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/etc" includes="log4j.xml"/>
        </copy>
    </target>


    <target name="run" depends="build" description="Execute application located in 'build'">
        <java classname="com.my.demo.app.Main" fork="yes" classpathref="run.classpath"/>
    </target>

    <target name="dist" depends="clean,build" description="Create distributable jar">
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}"/>
        <jar jarfile="${dist.dir}/DemoApp.jar" basedir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
        <manifestclasspath property="manifest.classpath" jarfile="${dist.dir}/DemoApp.jar">
            <classpath refid="run.classpath" />
        </manifestclasspath>

        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/DemoApp.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.my.demo.app.Main"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.classpath}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="runjar" description="Execute jar created with dist target">
        <java jar="${dist.dir}/DemoApp.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

**app.properties**

```
build.dir=${basedir}/build
build.classes.dir=${build.dir}/classes
src.dir=${basedir}/src
lib.dir=${basedir}/lib
dist.dir=${basedir}/dist

read.from.app.properties=This is read from app.properties
```

Thank You.

Comment: Embedded the image for you.  Thanks for calling out that you needed someone with more rep to do that.

Comment: Can you try using a manifest of: Class-Path: build/classes/ build/img/ etc

Comment: Doesn't work, when executing the jar I get the error:
runjar:
     [java] Error: Could not find or load main class com.my.demo.app.Main